# I'm unable to import packages in Python though I can see they are installed

Tags: python-3.x, package, conda

I am very new to python.
Using python 3.11.2 and Mac OS
I am using VS Code which crashed whilst I was working. When I restarted, several of my installed packages seem to be unavailable.
I keep getting:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'habanero'

I have checked that the packages are installed either on Pypi or conda-forge which they are. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling. Nothing seems to resolve the issue.
Why might this be?

Comment: Were you working from within a virtual environment on VSCode? It might have selected the wrong interpreter when it reopened

Comment: Thank you so much! This was it. Can't believe I was scouring the internet for so long for such a quick fix.